# -[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)' *** First throw call stack:

Tags: ios, objective-c

> -[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'
>   *** First throw call stack:

```
#pragma mark - Collection view data source
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return  totalCountQuestion;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    QuestionCell *Quizcell=(QuestionCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"QuizCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Quizcell.TotalQuestions.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.item+1]; 
    Question *question = self.currentQuiz[indexPath.row];
    Quizcell.image_Crt_Wrg.image=(question.selectedResponse == question.correctResponse) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"Correct_images.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"WrongShape.png"];
    return Quizcell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    index_value=indexPath.row;
}

//| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    Quiz *newQuiz = [[Quiz alloc] initWithQuestionsPlistAtURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:TopicListArray[TopicIndex] withExtension:@"plist"]];
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]objectAtIndex:index_value];
    _selectedCell=selectedIndexPath.item;
    ExplanationViewController *FirstQuestionVC = (ExplanationViewController*)[segue.destinationViewController viewControllers][0];
    FirstQuestionVC.currentQuiz=newQuiz;
    FirstQuestionVC.selectedCell=_selectedCell;
}
```

Any one help me,..

Comment: improve your format...

Comment: Start by pointing out which line causes the error.

Comment: what is totalCountQuestion its array or integer value

Comment: that one is total question store like a integer value

Comment: Error : If i click collection cell {0 r 1} it will not show this error but if i click any other cells its showing error  -[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)' *** First throw call stack:

Comment: just check that you totalCountQuestion and self.currentQuiz count is equal
if both are not equal then beyond bounds error will show

Comment: one more for Ex : i have 10 quest its showing like a collection cell,if i click the first {1,2,6,7,8,9,10,...ect }i didnt get that error if i click collection cell { 3,4,5} it will showing like that error...i don't knw how it like error comes could u help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I would use

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

instead of

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

But my guess is your problem is in

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 //...
 NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]objectAtIndex:index_value];
_selectedCell=selectedIndexPath.item;
```

I guess only one item is selected, so you should use

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] firstObject];
```

and *NSIndexPath* doesn't provide a property *item*.

I would implement *pushViewController:animated:* in *collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath*. For you maybe *performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:* is a option.

Comment: NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] firstObject];
Here,   what is the firstObject?

Comment: _indexPathsForSelectedItems_ returns an array of _NSIndexPath_ objects. _firstObject_ basically equals _someArray[0]_ or _[someArray objectAtIndex:0]_. But to be clear I wouldn't go that way. If the problem is in _prepareForSegue_ I would implement *collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath*, access the model  like _currentQuiz[indexPath.row]_ and push a new viewcontroller.

Comment: Sorry,..right now only i found my exact problem : if user click the collection cell that will go to the tableview and showing that current selected question.

Comment: The problem is the quiz options if quiz option would b 3 it will not crashing otherwise if 2 options it will crashing.....i wasted ur time sorry for that...could u help this problem..?

Comment: this is my code ; - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        NSString *CheckNil=[NSString stringWithString:self.currentQuiz[self.questionIndex].quizImage];
        Ans_Array_Count=(int)self.currentQuiz[self.questionIndex].responses.count;
        return (([CheckNil  isEqual: @"nil"] ) ? Ans_Array_Count:1);
    }
    else
    {
        return self.currentQuiz[self.questionIndex].responses.count;
    }
}

Comment: I would recommend using [enums](http://lanceulmer.com/2012/10/23/use-enum-to-keep-track-of-uitableview-sections/) instead of hard coded indexes. I don't get the idea behind _CheckNil_. Why not _(Ans_Array_Count>0) ? Ans_Array_Count : 1_. If you want to continue developing on this platform please read [Apple CodingGuidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1) at some point.